# Problem installing Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10

Tags: system-installation, windows-10

Windows 10 is installed on my computer and I am trying to dual-boot it with Ubuntu 16.04.

I have two partitions with plenty of free space.

In the installation menu of Ubuntu 16.04, "install ubuntu along side windows 10" is not listed as an option.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please update your question with the output of `sudo parted -l` from the live DVD/USB.

Comment: Did you turn off Windows 10 always on hibernation which it calls fast start up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto he didn't install it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: @Hi-Angel, so what? "from the live DVD/USB" means exactly that.

Comment: @DavidFoerster this Q asks **why** not *how*. ;)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: Do you seriously believe that OP is interested in the reason (assuming that someone can even answer that)? ^.^

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes. The reason is valuable information to understand why it happens and what one should do to install Ubuntu despite this "issue". Surely we can answer that if we see the current partition layout, which I precisely asked for in another comment.